# Min Enclosing for a bounding rect?

Tags: c++, math, opencv, geometry

I would like to compute the minumum enclosing circle of a bounding rectangle (a window) using opencv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [minEnclosingCircle](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=minenclosingcircle#minenclosingcircle) passing in the four points of the rectangle.

Thinking about it again, for a regular rectangle (Rect struct) it can easily calculated.

The center of the circle (both enclosing and inside) is simply (x + width / 2, y + height / 2). The radius for the enclosing circle is the distance from center to one of the corners (read: pythagoras). The radius for the inside circle is simply min(width, height)/2.

Note: There's an infinite number of inside circles for a rectangle that's not a sqaure. My method just uses the center most.

Comment: Also What about the circle that maxium fits the rectangle ?

Comment: The Rect struct has x, y, width and height.

Top-Left: (x, y), 
Top-Right: (x + width, y), 
Bottom-Left: (x, y + height), 
Bottom-Right: (x + width, y + height)

Comment: For the other circle, I'd probably calculate it on my own. Actually, if it's a regular rect (not rotated) you should do that for both cases. See updated answer (soon).

Comment: From the above properties, can I get the maximum radius of a circle that can be drawn inside or enclosing the rectangle?

Comment: Check my updated answer for radius. Take pen and paper and you'll see how easy it is.